# How can I create a custom titlebar for all of my activities?

Tags: java, android, themes, android-layout

I have seen many examples of creating a custom titlebar: http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/android-how-to-add-custom-title-bar/

Is there a simpler way of doing this? I think it is a bit overkill to have to implement the custom titlebar code in onCreate() for every activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use an include? Put the design of your standard titlebar into a layout XML file, and then include it in each activity layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_title_bar" />
```

And then create my_title_bar.xml to contain the contents of the bar.

If you have clickable views in the title bar you'll need a little code, but you could subclass Activity to provide click methods.

Comment: Could you provide an example as to where to put the include if I have a layout with LinearLayout and lots of views inside it?

Answer (score 3):

Create an Activity base class and write the code to draw the custom title bar.  Derive your Activities from this.  If you want the title text of your title bar to change, you could also write a setter method in your Activity base class.

Comment: Should the creation of custom title bar method go in the onCreate of the Activity from which we derive all the Activities? Because, if that is the case, the title bar appears blank. So could you provide an example