# Applying a custom title bar for the entire application

Tags: android, android-layout

I actually want to apply a custom title bar (kind of like the Action Bar), but since i'm developing for Froyo, I actually need to have it in a xml file. The trivial way to do this is to just write the code to create the title bar in each of the activities.

I did search around for some efficient ways and found this on SO

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249783/how-can-i-create-a-custom-titlebar-for-all-of-my-activities)

There are 2 solutions proposed over there, but I am having problems in implementing them.

1. To include the layout of your title bar in the layout of all the Activities. My question is say I have a sample layout as follows, where should the include tag go and do I need to use Theme.NoTitleBar theme for the application in order to get it working?
2. To subclass Activity and then derive all of my Activities from that. Should the custom Title bar creation method be defined in the onCreate method of the subclassed Activity. Because if I do this, the custom title bar does appear, but it appears blank. No buttons,etc.. are present on it.

Thanks in advance for any help you provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The  tag belongs inside the top level view container (linear layout/relative layout). Yes use NoTitleBar so you don't have the Android provided title bar in your app window.
2. There is obviously an issue with your code there, with out any code in your post I cannot help you.